# RoR API RABL collection to array

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3, api, rabl

RABL Current Code :

```
object @region
attributes :id, :name, :latitude, :longitude, :region_id
child :sub_regions do
  attributes :name
end
```

I get the following output :

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "test",
    "latitude": "30.932351",
    "longitude": "92.83391",
    "region_id": 1,
    "sub_regions": [{
            "name": "1"
        }, {
            "name": "2"
        }, {
            "name": "3"
        }, {
            "name": "4"
        }, {
            "name": "5"
        }, {
            "name": "6"
        }, {
            "name": "7"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to remove name attribute and just display the values as an array
But what I want is to convert the collection to an array like the output here :

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "test",
    latitude: "30.932351",
    longitude: "92.83391",
    region_id: 1,
    sub_regions: [
            "1",
            "2",
            "3",
            "4",
            "5",
            "6",
            "7"
    ]
}
```

The closest I can get to this is by this RABL code :

```
code :sub_regions do |s|
  s["name"]
end


{
    {
          id: 1,
          name: "test",
          "latitude": "30.932351",
          "longitude": "92.83391",
          region_id: 1,
          sub_regions: "1"
    }

}
```

By the above code block in show.json.rabl it displays only the first element, how do i make it an array with all the elements?

Answer (score 2):

joe nayyar had the right idea in his answer, but there's a cleaner way than using `object false`.

```
child :sub_regions do
  attributes :name
end
```

becomes...

```
node :sub_regions do |region|
  region.sub_regions.collect(&:name)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you used object @region when you should have used collection @region

Comment: No. One object region has an array of sub regions but there is only one region.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone lazy roaming around for solution like me, as RABL is on top of the ruby code base you can do something like:

```
object false 
node :region, :object_root => false do 
{:id => @region.id, :name => @region.name, :latitude=> @region.latitude, :region_id =>  @region.region_id, :sub_regions=>@region.sub_regions.collect(&:name)}
end
```